# Angular 7 - Get logged in username after Azure AD authentication

Tags: angular, active-directory, azure-active-directory, angular7

I have hosted a new Angular 7 App in Azure app service. Also added Azure AD authentication for same based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

the AD authentication is working (when i take site, it goes to microsoft login page and once login retruns back)

My issue now is how will be get the logged in username to show in UI? i searched many links but nothing that helps for a beginner like me. can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link helped me to solved. this is explained pretty clear

https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular6-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this [Configure Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad)

Comment: Thank you . But this does not seems to be of Angular 7. It seems to be for angular.js app which is diffrernt from angular7

Comment: I have found this for you [click here](https://www.digital-moves.eu/2018/07/19/authentication-with-azure-ad-angular-6-client-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.adalService.userInfo.profile.name` to get the username for additional information you can check the responce here `this.adalService.userInfo` if you are using "**adal-angular4**" Module.